# GitHub shows a submodule instead of a subfolder

Tags: node.js, git, github

Git unconsciously created submodule from my subfolder where there was .git lately. I deleted .git and there's no git files like .gitignore but still can't add files to this subfolder. It looks like this

[image: git folders]

And inside io-invoices (submodule) I've got

[image: submodule folder]

I've checked hidden files.

Comment: Please, replace images with acrual text. You can use Markdown lists to organize it. Only use images where there is no alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to remove that directory from the Git tree and re-add it later. Backup everything before!

```sh
git rm --cached ./io-invoices
git add ./io-invoices
```